# Using Braintree with .NET MAUI

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, maui, braintree

I'm attempting to use Braintree inside an .NET MAUI app.

In Xamarin, I previously used the NAXAM Braintree libraries, but they appear to be deprecated and not updated to .NET 7.

My solution was to use the Android and iOS projects from Braintree and create native binding projects.

For Android this ran nice and smooth, but iOS is giving me fits.

I used the Braintree.iOS code base to build and create fat Swift frameworks following the [Xamarin binding guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/binding-swift/walkthrough).

Following the guide and running the app on the simulator works well.

However, running the app on my actual device causes the app to crash before the debugger can even attach. Below is the output log from VS for Mac:

```
2023-07-27 16:20:03.274 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEDebugger.VariablesViewQuickLookProvider for extension Xcode.IDEDebugger.SpriteKitQuickLookProvider of plug-in com.apple.IDESpriteKitParticleEditor
2023-07-27 16:20:03.275 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEDebugger.VariablesViewQuickLookProvider for extension Xcode.SpriteKit.GKStateMachineQuickLookProvider of plug-in com.apple.IDESpriteKitParticleEditor
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.WatchApplication of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOSSimulator.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.Application of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.Tool of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOSSimulator.ViewDescriber of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.IntentsService-AppExtension of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType.WatchOS.Bundle of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.WatchKit2-AppExtension of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice.WatchOS.BundleInfo of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOS.ViewDescriber of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.Framework of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.ExtensionKitAppExtension of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.WatchOS.AppExtension of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.watchOS.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.288 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEiPhoneSupport.TargetEditor for extension Xcode.IDEiPhoneSupport.TargetEditor.WatchOS.Application of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUIFramework of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.Application of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.AppExtension of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.tvOSSimulator.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.ExtensionKitAppExtension of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorType.appletvos.Bundle of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ATVSimulator.ViewDescriber of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DeviceIconProvider for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DeviceIconProvider.AppleTV of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ViewDescriber for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.ATV.ViewDescriber of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.DataSourceConnection for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.tvOS.DataSourceConnectionTargetHub of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.TargetSummaryEditor.IDEAppleTVSupportUI.XPC of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.289 mlaunch[75835:788529] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice for extension Xcode.Xcode3ProjectSupport.InfoEditorSlice.appletvos.BundleTargetInfo of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEAppleTVSupportUI
2023-07-27 16:20:03.717 mlaunch[75835:788625] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default (DVTEnableCoreDevice=(null))
2023-07-27 16:20:03.903 mlaunch[75835:788625] Thread Pool Worker DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21780/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTExtendedPlatformInfo.m:79
Details:  DVTExtendedPlatformInfo: Synthesized watchos Extended Platform Info because no plugin existed to provide it or that plugin was not loaded
Object:   <DVTExtendedPlatformInfo>
Method:   +extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600000d22fc0>{number = 10, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2023-07-27 16:20:03.903 mlaunch[75835:788625] Thread Pool Worker DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21780/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTExtendedPlatformInfo.m:79
Details:  DVTExtendedPlatformInfo: Synthesized iphonesimulator Extended Platform Info because no plugin existed to provide it or that plugin was not loaded
Object:   <DVTExtendedPlatformInfo>
Method:   +extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600000d22fc0>{number = 10, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2023-07-27 16:20:03.903 mlaunch[75835:788625] Thread Pool Worker DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21780/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTExtendedPlatformInfo.m:79
Details:  DVTExtendedPlatformInfo: Synthesized watchsimulator Extended Platform Info because no plugin existed to provide it or that plugin was not loaded
Object:   <DVTExtendedPlatformInfo>
Method:   +extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600000d22fc0>{number = 10, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
2023-07-27 16:20:03.903 mlaunch[75835:788625] Thread Pool Worker DVTAssertions: Warning in /System/Volumes/Data/SWE/Apps/DT/BuildRoots/BuildRoot7/ActiveBuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/DVTFrameworks/DVTFrameworks-21780/DVTFoundation/DeveloperStructure/DVTExtendedPlatformInfo.m:79
Details:  DVTExtendedPlatformInfo: Synthesized iphoneos Extended Platform Info because no plugin existed to provide it or that plugin was not loaded
Object:   <DVTExtendedPlatformInfo>
Method:   +extendedPlatformInfoForPlatformIdentifier:error:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x600000d22fc0>{number = 10, name = (null)}
Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
```

Below is the crash log from Xcode:

```
Incident Identifier: 951BFC4D-D0A3-4BED-BBE6-10BF483CDA2D
CrashReporter Key:   59e4cf68065c9538b21767f2c281d588c63e79fd
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,1
Process:             XXXXXXXXXX [1866]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/XXXXX
Identifier:          com.XXXXX.XX
Version:             1.0 (1)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.XXXXX.XX [594]

Date/Time:           2023-07-27 14:21:07.5710 -0500
Launch Time:         2023-07-27 14:21:07.2090 -0500
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.5.1 (20F770750d)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.02.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000000000001e
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000000000001e
VM Region Info: 0x1e is not in any region.  Bytes before following region: 68719476706
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      UNUSED SPACE AT START
--->  
      commpage (reserved)     1000000000-7000000000 [384.0G] ---/--- SM=NUL  ...(unallocated)
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [1866]

Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:   Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                        0x1aa233c74 objc_opt_class + 48
1   XXXXX                          0x10538fabc xamarin_create_classes + 15153852 (registrar.mm:90953)
2   XXXXX                          0x1052b2b24 xamarin_invoke_registration_methods() + 14248740 (main.arm64.mm:18)
3   XXXXX                          0x1052b2a30 xamarin_setup_impl() + 14248496 (main.arm64.mm:0)
4   XXXXX                          0x104f1f82c xamarin_main + 10500140 (monotouch-main.m:276)
5   XXXXX                          0x1052b2b6c main + 14248812 (main.arm64.mm:84)
6   dyld                                   0x1d06eadec start + 2220

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x210f18b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x210f18b74 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x210f18b74 start_wqthread + 0


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000106265cc8   x1: 0x00000001ac999aa8   x2: 0xffffffffffffffe0   x3: 0x0000000280e913a0
    x4: 0x0000000280e91400   x5: 0x0000000040e00000   x6: 0x0000000282a9f900   x7: 0x0000000000000430
    x8: 0x0000000000000001   x9: 0x000000010593be00  x10: 0x0000000283f99500  x11: 0x0000000283f99510
   x12: 0x0000000000000003  x13: 0x0000000000000001  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0xffffffffffffffff
   x16: 0x0000000000000000  x17: 0x0000000000000000  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x00000001052b2b2c
   x20: 0x0000000105aa8000  x21: 0x0000000105aa9910  x22: 0x000000016b8e38d0  x23: 0x00000001d074e0fe
   x24: 0x000000016b8e3850  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000000000000  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016b8e3610   lr: 0x000000010538fabc
    sp: 0x000000016b8d4a30   pc: 0x00000001aa233c74 cpsr: 0x60000000
   far: 0x000000000000001e  esr: 0x92000006 (Data Abort) byte read Translation fault

Binary Images:
       0x10451c000 -        0x1057cffff XXXXX arm64  <7ff68d752f1930b29a47819a69e1abf1> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/XXXXX
       0x105bf0000 -        0x105cdbfff libHarfBuzzSharp arm64  <b70950ccc85f3515ae8797452f337d93> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/libHarfBuzzSharp.framework/libHarfBuzzSharp
       0x106458000 -        0x10699ffff libSkiaSharp arm64  <e731a267097031bda384c26188c796ca> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/libSkiaSharp.framework/libSkiaSharp
       0x105b10000 -        0x105b1ffff AirshipBasement arm64  <723cdb23c9b33cecaca1346500883986> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/AirshipBasement.framework/AirshipBasement
       0x107030000 -        0x107383fff AirshipCore arm64  <bf221216570735a993ad0cf13abb8e4b> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/AirshipCore.framework/AirshipCore
       0x105cf4000 -        0x105d27fff AirshipMessageCenter arm64  <5917e1fe0675355183453e4ef5f4c098> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/AirshipMessageCenter.framework/AirshipMessageCenter
       0x105b68000 -        0x105b77fff FirebaseCore arm64  <3f50ffa42e2c3f10bad34d29de3a608e> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/StopAndShopRx.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/FirebaseCore
       0x105b34000 -        0x105b3bfff FirebaseCoreDiagnostics arm64  <9d982b363ab230ddb9e32a6004e26e9c> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics.framework/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics
       0x105eac000 -        0x105ed7fff GTMSessionFetcher arm64  <84d0325992313d748fa8fee8d60fb6fb> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/GTMSessionFetcher.framework/GTMSessionFetcher
       0x106028000 -        0x106057fff GoogleAPIClientForREST arm64  <1f89d70b7f623350957ac8eeaa5e90ef> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/GoogleAPIClientForREST.framework/GoogleAPIClientForREST
       0x105dc0000 -        0x105ddffff GoogleDataTransport arm64  <55d86e7837703932ac2cc9db93e53a7d> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/GoogleDataTransport.framework/GoogleDataTransport
       0x105d64000 -        0x105d73fff FBLPromises arm64  <fb242e46c19339878439ebba20a8f2db> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/FBLPromises.framework/FBLPromises
       0x105b9c000 -        0x105ba7fff GoogleToolboxForMac arm64  <9ebfff25122e37389e770c30e0c99b16> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/GoogleToolboxForMac.framework/GoogleToolboxForMac
       0x105f74000 -        0x105f8ffff GoogleUtilities arm64  <ceeb119d01e4353a9a142f9599f8f6ff> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/GoogleUtilities.framework/GoogleUtilities
       0x105b4c000 -        0x105b53fff nanopb arm64  <209b8d5a160e3d7395c9ec3eccbe1235> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/nanopb.framework/nanopb
       0x1061b8000 -        0x1061ebfff leveldb arm64  <705804dddf153aaf9342d696af03bf2f> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/leveldb.framework/leveldb
       0x106334000 -        0x10637bfff Protobuf arm64  <9447cd88c361327788f90d8681b27997> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/Protobuf.framework/Protobuf
       0x106a08000 -        0x106a47fff FirebaseCrashlytics arm64  <613915bc7f61349fa2dd4071e4307aa1> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/FirebaseCrashlytics.framework/FirebaseCrashlytics
       0x105fc4000 -        0x105fdbfff FirebaseInstallations arm64  <9243fd05262f37e1b589135955eb9569> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/FirebaseInstallations.framework/FirebaseInstallations
       0x106ac0000 -        0x106ad7fff ZipArchive arm64  <aa47fc3948d033cda0d96eec10318eb3> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/ZipArchive.framework/ZipArchive
       0x106244000 -        0x10625ffff BraintreeCard arm64  <1d8b552070513355a04c1b463413d4c5> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/BraintreeCard.framework/BraintreeCard
       0x106c6c000 -        0x106caffff BraintreeCore arm64  <53ef5161c16f35999cdfde9039759c95> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/BraintreeCore.framework/BraintreeCore
       0x106d68000 -        0x106da7fff BraintreeDataCollector arm64  <9358437d7dd0376fa4fc7f00bd6b249e> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/B6B8C5FD-FDA0-4C1E-9D5A-76C6FDC8AE26/XXXXX.app/Frameworks/BraintreeDataCollector.framework/BraintreeDataCollector
       0x105f50000 -        0x105f5bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <695a8449aae838b6851cced0b1176f03> /private/preboot/Cryptexes/OS/usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
       0x1aa22c000 -        0x1aa26ff9f libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <085a190c621438eaaccb428c3e8afa65> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
       0x1d06d5000 -        0x1d075aa23 dyld arm64e  <6987370ac3853135a27f6731706bcbd8> /usr/lib/dyld
       0x210f18000 -        0x210f23ff3 libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <56698309210a313797d414e4604b1117> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
               0x0 - 0xffffffffffffffff ??? unknown-arch  <00000000000000000000000000000000> ???

EOF
```

Any thoughts or ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this is not use the latest version of Braintree. Switching to their 5.x branch worked with some tweaks.